# chromedriverを使用したスクレイピング時に、headlessモードだとブラウザでpdf表示のスクリーンショットを取得しても取得できません。

Tags: centos, web-scraping, selenium, chromedriver

chromedriverを使用したスクレイピング時にheadlessモードだと、ブラウザでpdf表示のスクリーンショットを取得しても取得できません。取得できるよい方法がありましたら、お教えいただけると助かります。

環境：
centos7
chromedriver使用
python3からseleniumを使用しスクレイピング

Comment: headless有無両方のソースや動作の説明を追記した方が答えが得られ易いでしょう。

Comment: こちら [chromedriverを使用したスクレイピング時に、headlessモードだとブラウザでpdf表示のスクリーンショットを取得しても取得できません。](https://teratail.com/questions/270346) にも出されていますが、そちらでもコメントに未反応のようです。

Comment: 似たような悩みを投稿されているみたいだったので、私が投稿した記事を共有させていただきます。
サイトによるかもしれませんが、chromeのトップページ自体はheadlessモードで問題なく実行できることを確認しております。
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/68858/selenium%e3%81%aeheadless%e3%83%a2%e3%83%bc%e3%83%89%e3%82%92%e4%bd%bf%e7%94%a8%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e6%99%82%e3%81%ab-itunes-connect%e3%81%ae%e3%83%ad%e3%82%b0%e3%82%a4%e3%83%b3%e3%83%9a%e3%83%bc%e3%82%b8%e3%81%ae%e3%82%b9%e3%82%af%e3%82%b7%e3%83%a7%e3%82%92%e5%8f%96%e5%be%97%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84 ご参考になれば幸いです。