# selenium の find_element_by_xpath でエラーが出力される

Tags: python, selenium

商品をカートに入れるプログラムを書いているのですが、上手く動作しません。

ユーザのプロファイルを指定してseleniumを実行したくて追加しました。

```
# options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=user')
# options.add_argument('--profile-directory=profile')
# options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9222')
```

これらのコードが原因と言う所までわかったのですが、これを無効にすると指定したユーザで実行出来ないので困っています。
3行目のコードはheadlessにするために使用しています。
下記のサイトを見て実装しました。

[seleniumのheadlessでプロファイルを使う際のエラー解消法](http://blog.sbfm.jp/archives/196)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

def add_cart(indexNum):
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument('--headless')
        # 以下のコードがあると、elementが取れないとエラー出力
        ## 下記のコードをコメントアウトすると正しく動作する。
        # options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=user')
        # options.add_argument('--profile-directory=profile')
        # options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9222')
        driver = webdriver.Chrome('selenium/chromedriver', options=options)

        indexNum = indexNum - 1
        url = 'https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/accessories/ona0i275t/u5ln1jxbe'
        #driver = self.driver
        driver.get(url)

        # 数量を指定
        element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="qty"]')
        print(element.text)
        select = Select(element)
        select.select_by_index(indexNum)
        
        # カートに入れる
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#add-remove-buttons > input").click()
        time.sleep(.2)

        # 下記のコードはカートに入った確認するためのテストコード
        driver.get('https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/cart')
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
        print(soup.body)
        driver.quit()

add_cart(1)
```

**エラー内容**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sup.py", line 197, in <module>
    Supreme.add_cart(1)
  File "sup.py", line 156, in add_cart
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="qty"]')
  File "/home/vagrant/anaconda3/envs/pinterest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "/home/vagrant/anaconda3/envs/pinterest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "/home/vagrant/anaconda3/envs/pinterest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/vagrant/anaconda3/envs/pinterest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="qty"]"}
```

どなたか詳しい方お力を貸して頂けないでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: こちら [seleniumのheadlessモードを使用した時に、iTunes Connectのログインページのスクショを取得したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/68858/26370) のように`--user-agent=`も指定する必要があるのでは？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。サイトのhtmlが取得出来るのでエージェントによるものではないと考えています。実際に追加して見たのですが、結果は同じでした。

Comment: 後は実施済みでしょうが確認のため、こちらの記事にあるユーザーとプロファイルのフォルダがChromeによる作業で作られているか？ですかね。[SeleniumでChromeのユーザープロファイルを指定しつつ同時に自分もChromeを使う方法](https://qiita.com/Hidenatsu/items/e43ba04b4b5f710784e6), [Python + Selenium + Chrome で自動ログインいくつか](https://qiita.com/memakura/items/dbe7f6edadd456da1c5d)

Comment: はいそうです！chromeによって作成されています。

Comment: ただなぜusr-dataとprofileを別々で設定されているのか分からないです。2つは同じものではないのでしょうか？

Comment: 画面の読み込みが終わってないと思い、ページ取得後に10秒待機させて画面の模写が終わるのを待って見たのですがダメでした。

Comment: おそらくusr-dataとprofileには独立した役割があるのでしょう。こんな記事があるので。[SeleniumでChromeのprofileが変更できない](https://teratail.com/questions/122418) 結局実現出来ないなら、headlessは諦めてusr-dataとprofileだけ分けて動作させてみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: すいません。解決しました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

前回カートに入れた商品が残ったままだった事でページのHTMLが変化しており要素が存在しなかっただけでした。
ご迷惑をおかけしました。

`driver.delete_all_cookies()`でアクセス前にcookieを削除したら上手く動作しました。